How to build libircclient with cmake/ExternalProject?
I'm trying to build libircclient, which uses a configure/make/make install/autotools system. What I have so far is:
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(ircclient
  GIT_REPOSITORY git@github.com:shaoner/libircclient.git
  GIT_TAG        v1.6.0
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND cd ../ircclient/ && ./configure
  BUILD_COMMAND make -C ../ircclient/
)

However:

I need to cd into the source directory to build. For whatever reason, ircclient doesn't seem to be able to build out-of-tree*. I think I need a better way of finding the source directory and telling cmake to build in there - thoughts? Maybe something like WORKING_DIRECTORY ${ircclient_DOWNLOAD_DIR} but I don't know how to find what ${ircclient_*} variables are available to me.

The next thing cmake wants to do is cd <build-dir>/ircclient-prefix/src/ircclient-build && make install, but that would obviously try and try and install in system directories unless I do something to tell it otherwise. I know I can give the configure script a --prefix but I don't know where should I tell libircclient to install?


* It leaves the Makefile in the source directory, but some other files in the build directory, so ends up failing because either way it doesn't have all the right files unless you configure from the source directory.

For perform in-source build with ExternalProject, you may set BUILD_IN_SOURCE flag. As for selecting install directory, it is up to you. You may even choose to not install the subproject at all, by setting INSTALL_COMMAND option to empty string.
